# Java: how to index elements that have an associated interval?

Tags: java, data-structures, indexing, intervals

Suppose I have a number of objects with a start value and an end value that are comparable via some Comparator.

What kind of collection can I use to make an index of the objects, so that given an arbitrary value V, I can find all the objects where V is between the start and end values?

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree. You should probably ignore the complicated "centered tree" construction that occurs first there, and look instead at the "augmented tree" which is the standard way to do it.

Comment: sweet, it even gives a Java example.

Answer (score 1):

I some circumstances, a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), possibly with [temporal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) support, may be a suitable alternative.

Comment: That's perfectly understandable. I'll leave the answer for future reference.